# sensors blackberry 10 webworks

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I'm a newbie in BB10 Webworks... I am doing some experiments with the dev alpha's magnetometer...

how can I put these to work? I tried

```
function magCallback(sensor, data) {
   $("#xvalueut").html(data.x);
   $("#yvalueut").html(data.y);
   $("#zvalueut").html(data.z);
   }
   blackberry.event.addEventListener("devicemagnetometer", magCallback);
```

and didn't worked, I also put `<feature id="blackberry.sensors" />` in the config file, and inserted a `<script src="local:///chrome/webworks.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in the index.html

I hope you can help me...

Answer (score 0):

We have a really good sample app in our GitHub repo that you'll probably want to check-out.  It deals with all of the sensors you can access via BlackBerry WebWorks.

Here's the link: [Sensors Sample App](https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/Sensors)